# Access Hive metastore table data using Templeton/WebHcat respt API's for Last Updated Time

Tags: hive-metastore

All, I am working in a Hadoop project and I have requirement to get last scooped timestamp of a database using Templeton/WebHcat Rest API's.

Please post if any one knows the process.

Thanks in advance

regards,
Joshua

Comment: What is a _"scooped timestamp"_??

Comment: Hive Metastore does not keep track of data uploads, since they can occur at HDFS level without notification. You will get the "last DDL time" at best.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Scoop time is the time when data pushed from files to database tables. (done by using AutosysJob).

Comment: Could you please help me how to get last DDL Time by using Templeton rest API.

Comment: No idea. I have used Hive `descrive extended` command, also the Metastore java API, but never WebHCat. Always thought it was a legacy band-aid _(except that Azure seems to use it a lot, which makes sense since Microsoft stuff does not play well with Java...)_

Comment: You may also inspect the data files, using WebHDFS or HttpFS if you really need a REST API, to check their "last modified" timestamp.